# DateFormatter ofPattern not returning the correct date

Tags: java, java-time, localdate

I am using `DateTimeFormatter` to format my `LocalDate` which has the value `31 Jan 2019`. 
When I execute the code below, the correct date is returned:

```
// 31, Dec, 2018
System.out.println(LocalDate.now().minusMonths(1).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd, MMM, yyyy")));
```

But if I execute the code below, the date is returned with the correct date, month but the wrong year:

```
// 31, Dec, 2019
System.out.println(LocalDate.now().minusMonths(1).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd, MMM, YYYY")));
```

What I am confused about is that, if I also use the same pattern above and I just `minusDays(30)` which makes my expected to be `01 Dec 2018`, the correct result is returned:

```
// 01, Dec, 2018
System.out.println(LocalDate.now().minusMonths(1).minusDays(30).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd, MMM, YYYY")));
```

Could using `YYYY` in the `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd, MMM, YYYY"))` pattern because this?

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*Today's date is 31st of January 2019*/

//        2018-12-31
        System.out.println(LocalDate.now().minusMonths(1));

//        31, Dec, 2018
        System.out.println(LocalDate.now().minusMonths(1).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd, MMM, yyyy")));

//        31, Dec, 2019
        System.out.println(LocalDate.now().minusMonths(1).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd, MMM, YYYY")));

//        01, Dec, 2018
        System.out.println(LocalDate.now().minusMonths(1).minusDays(30).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd, MMM, YYYY")));

//        31, Dec, 2018
        System.out.println(LocalDate.now().minusMonths(1).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd, MMM, uuuu")));
    }
}
```

Comment: yyyy != YYYY. **Read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns): `y` = year-of-era, `Y` = week-based-year. Of source the `y` vs `Y` produce different results and is why you see different values.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I understood reading the documentation is because of this:
"YY" specifies the week-based year numbering and for normal year numbering, you should use "yy" instead.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

EDIT:

The week and year numbering in an ISO-8601 calendar is different from a standard Gregorian calendar. Here’s how January 2nd, 2011 would be represented:

```
Calendar System     Week Number    Year Number
Standard Gregorian     1                  2011
ISO-8601               52                 2010
```

The Gregorian leap cycle, which has 97 leap days spread across 400 years, contains a whole number of weeks (20871). In every cycle there are 71 years with an additional 53rd week (corresponding to the Gregorian years that contain 53 Thursdays). An average year is exactly 52.1775 weeks long; months (​1⁄12 year) average at exactly 4.348125 weeks.

An ISO week-numbering year (also called ISO year informally) has 52 or 53 full weeks. That is 364 or 371 days instead of the usual 365 or 366 days. The extra week is sometimes referred to as a leap week, although ISO 8601 does not use this term.

For more info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date

Comment: @Savior I have edited the question

Comment: The “standard Gregorian calendar” does not define a week number at all. Instead each locale defines its own scheme for numbering weeks and assigning them to week-based years.

Comment: That's not what Wikipedia says: "An average year is exactly 52.1775 weeks long; months (​1⁄12 year) average at exactly 4.348125 weeks."

Comment: There isn’t any average year anywhere in the calendar, it’s only an abstract concept. So there’s no contradiction.

Comment: Yes I agree on that...